# How to Fix problem child is'nt defined in drawer flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class Drawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text("Anus"),
            accountEmail: Text("Anus@gmail.com"),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533227268428-f9ed0900fb3b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1158&q=80"),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text("Account"),
            subtitle: Text("Personal"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.edit),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.email),
            title: Text("Email"),
            subtitle: Text("anus@gmail.com"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.send),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**How To Fix this Problem In flutter**

> I Want to Create Drawer but when i try to make drawer in new file for drawer **The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.**

Answer (score 0):

You used same Widget at definition of that widget.
Here is a working code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Drawer();
  }
}

class Drawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: Text("Anus"),
          accountEmail: Text("Anus@gmail.com"),
          currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533227268428-f9ed0900fb3b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1158&q=80"),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text("Account"),
          subtitle: Text("Personal"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.edit),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.email),
          title: Text("Email"),
          subtitle: Text("anus@gmail.com"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.send),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue stems from the fact that you used the Name Drawer for the class (your custom widget), which means that the compiler won't know which Drawer widget to use, either the Drawer from the material library or the Drawer that you just defined.

to fix this issue just change the name of the class to AppDrawer or any other name and the compiler will start recognizing that you're trying to use the Drawer defined in the material library.